# how to select every 1000 revolutions in table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, group-by

I have a table that has this data in it:

[image]

I am trying to create a calculation that involves every 1000 revs. For instance I need to calculate how many times an event occurs every 1000 revolutions.

How can I create this query? It's escaping me at the moment how to do this exactly. I need to group the revs by every 1000 basically. Any ideas? I'm not trying to get every 1000th RECORD - I'm using the actual values in the 'revs' field. That's what I need to group by every 1000. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATED QUESTION:

[image]

I need to count how many rows between that first row (with revs @ 43992139) and the next 1000 revs. The next row in the table is (43993401 - a little over 1000 stitches - the "Count" (the column with the ----!---) of faults for that would only be 1.

In some cases I might end up with 3 fault rows for 1000 revs. I don't want to alter my data - just count how many rows for every 1000 revs. I hope that helps a little.

Comment: That looks like a job for a pivot table or a histogram. Sorry I can't tell you how to do either, but now you at least have a term you can Google. EDIT: I think lad2025's answer below would produce something quite like a histogram.

Comment: So, a question about basic arithmetic?

Comment: I know the concept is simple - just couldn't seem to put it together sql-wise in my head. :) Having a moment I guess...

Comment: Do you just need to calculate the difference relative to the first row and then group as per @lad2025's answer? I get the impression this is a brand new table of data you've added.

Comment: It's not a brand new table - it's a brand new calculation they're wanting that I'm trying to put into a view. If that first column is revs and the third columns are faults - they're wanting to know how many faults occur for every 1000 stitches. I'm actually trying to calculate the differences between the rows now - but the row ids are not consecutive (so that poses another problem). I've pulled this data from ANOTHER view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use integer division to make groups per 1000:

```
SELECT (revs DIV 1000)*1000 AS revs, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY (revs DIV 1000)*1000;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410317)**</kbd> <sub>SqlFiddle returns timeout so SQL Server demo</sub>

Example:

```
2003 DIV 1000 * 1000 -> 2000
2999 DIV 1000 * 1000 -> 2000
3001 DIV 1000 * 1000 -> 3000
```

<sup><kbd>[Semi-graphical histogram (ignore)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410430)</kbd></sup>

Comment: I think this might work - let me give it a go. If it is - I'll mark your answer. :) Thanks!!!

Comment: There's a large gap in revolutions between the first two rows. I won't be surprised if OP also wants to fill in the "missing" groups.

Comment: Updating Question with a little more detail - @lad2025 - I think this is really close...

Comment: I think I got it to work... need to double check math... Thanks @lad2025 and @shawnt00!!!!